# award points to a user each time they update their cpt post

Tags: custom-field, user-meta, conditional-content

I'm trying to find a way to award a single point to a user each time they update a specific cpt post they have published. The points would need to cumulate. Based on this value, i'd then like to have global conditional whereby, `IF user's points are greater than X then do this`.

Answer (score 1):

The `save_post` action fires when a post is updated and/or published, including when a new post is inserted. You can use it for custom post types also.

Assume that your CPT is book.

```
add_action( 'save_book', 'wpse63478_save' );
function wpse63478_save() {
        //Your Code to give point to user
}
```

Comment: Do you have any help for //Your code to give to user... i need the points to accumulate. thanks.

Comment: You can use `user_meta` to store points. Link 01 : https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_user_meta Link 02 : https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_user_meta. And there many tutorials on the internet. Just search on Google how to add user meta in WordPress. You can find lots of tutorials.